# What is the timezone name '\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc9\xbd\xb5\xd8\xb1\xea\xd7\xbc\xca\xb1\xbc\xe4'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, internationalization, timezone

I have a colleague whose computer won't run a Python script that uses the dateutil.tz module; there is a timezone name `'\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc9\xbd\xb5\xd8\xb1\xea\xd7\xbc\xca\xb1\xbc\xe4'` that shows up and in `dateutil.tz` there is this code:

```
def tzname_in_python2(namefunc):
    """Change unicode output into bytestrings in Python 2
    tzname() API changed in Python 3. It used to return bytes, but was changed
    to unicode strings
    """
    def adjust_encoding(*args, **kwargs):
        name = namefunc(*args, **kwargs)
        if name is not None and not PY3:
            name = name.encode()

        return name

    return adjust_encoding
```

which breaks because the string in question is not ASCII. What is this string? It doesn't look like valid Unicode:

```
>>> a = '\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc9\xbd\xb5\xd8\xb1\xea\xd7\xbc\xca\xb1\xbc\xe4'
>>> a.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\2\envs\emblaze\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

My python script contains

```
timezone = dateutil.tz.tzlocal()
```

and the resulting object fails to run `timezone.tzname(some_timestamp)` because of the non-ASCII nature of the timezone name.

Comment: Do you have any idea where this thing came from?

Comment: from `dateutil.tz.tz.local`

Comment: Take a look at what's in `time.tzname`, where `time` is the standard `time` module.

Comment: cool, thx, i'll try that

Comment: It evaluates as `('\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc9\xbd\xb5\xd8\xb1\xea\xd7\xbc\xca\xb1\xbc\xe4', '\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc9\xbd\xb5\xd8\xcf\xc4\xc1\xee\xca\xb1')`

Comment: the differing tails do seem to decode with utf16: &#xeab1;&#xbcd7;&#xb1ca;&#xe4bc; (볗뇊) and &#xc4cf;&#xeec1;&#xb1ca; (쓏뇊)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this happens again, there is a python module for this:

```
>>> import chardet
>>> z = b'\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc9\xbd\xb5\xd8\xb1\xea\xd7\xbc\xca\xb1\xbc\xe4'
>>> chardet.detect(z)
{'encoding': 'GB2312', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': 'Chinese'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I figured it out after a bunch of searching on the net. It's not UTF8 or UTF16; it seems to be [GB2312](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312) (or [GBK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding))) encoding, which can be decoded in Python (on MS Windows, at least) with the `gbk` codec:

```
>>> '\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc9\xbd\xb5\xd8\xb1\xea\xd7\xbc\xca\xb1\xbc\xe4'.decode('gbk')
u'\u7f8e\u56fd\u5c71\u5730\u6807\u51c6\u65f6\u95f4'
>>> '\xc3\xc0\xb9\xfa\xc9\xbd\xb5\xd8\xcf\xc4\xc1\xee\xca\xb1'.decode('gbk')
u'\u7f8e\u56fd\u5c71\u5730\u590f\u4ee4\u65f6'
```

which print out (in IPython Notebook) as

> 美国山地标准时间
>
> 美国山地夏令时

which Google Translate tells me represents "American Mountain Standard Time" and "American Mountain Summertime", respectively.